# C/C++ - socket - I get a wrong client adress

Tags: c++, sockets, client, ip-address

I want to get the adress of the client who sends a message to a server. I tried:

```
struct sockaddr_in client_sockaddr;
socklen_t tut = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
int valread;
int new_socket;
new_socket = accept(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_sockaddr,&tut);
valread = read( new_socket , clientMsg, _maxBufSize);
std::cout << "ip: "<< inet_ntoa(client_sockaddr.sin_addr) << std::endl;
```

inet_ntop gives the same result.

And I get an adress like 255.127.0.0 whereas the client adress is 192.168.42.80. It seems the ip I print changes from a try to another, but it's always like x.127.0.0.

Comment: What's the return value of accept?

Comment: ... and also read

Comment: It seems that the return value of accept is -1... -_-

Comment: always check return values of all calls.  In this case call perror to find out what is wrong.

Comment: This code snippet is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. If accept returns  -1  then check the errno (or call perror) to get the error details instead of simply ignoring any problems. And if accept returns -1 then client_sockaddr is not set by accept, thus you essentially output whatever happens to be in the uninitialized memory.

Comment: I thank you all for your help. It truly seems I solved the problem using recv() instead of accept() and using getpeername() to get the client ip adress.

Comment: @PAvelTchoudakov "*using recv() instead of accept()*" - that would only make sense if `sockFd` was not your server listening socket, but a previously `accept()`'ed socket.